# Copying data from R directly into word table via clipboard

Tags: r

Sometimes is could be quite convenient to directly copy data from R into Word.

For example if I have the following out put in R

```
c(1, 2)
[1] 1 2
```

When I copy the output and try to paste it into a Word table with 1 row and 2 columns it doesn't work as the output will only be copied in into only one cell.

Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: Why not save as csv as per the usual? Otherwise I am not sure If you can do that. You can paste it in excel and use excel to split it different cells but that is more work than saving and opening with say excel

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [flextable package](https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/overview.html) to create an MS Office table in Word.

```
library(flextable)
ft <- flextable(head(iris))
print(ft, preview = 'docx') # this will open a new word file with the table pasted in
```